# Regarding the summary of proofs of Prime Number Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I have read the proof of Prime Number Theorem given in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Apostol.

Now I want to know the following, I would be glad if someone can help

1-Whose proof did Tom Apostol follow in this book on Analytic Number Theory [which can be found here](https://b-ok.org/dl/2369279/7e6bd3)?
Was this proof given by Riemann?

2-What are all the other proofs that have been given for PNT?

3-Which proof do you think is worth studying?

Comment: If you mention something from a book or paper, either summarize the relevant passage or just post it in your question. The library’s closed, I can’t go get my copy of Apostol ;)

Comment: @AJY, edited the post

Comment: The [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#History_of_the_proof_of_the_asymptotic_law_of_prime_numbers) hasn't been proven by Riemann but around 1900, since then its description has been greatly improved, see the [references of Titchmarsh 1930](https://archive.org/details/zetafunctionofri032076mbp) (mentioning Littlewood)

Comment: oh, then whose proof is Apostol following?

Comment: Why do you think there are several proofs.

Comment: there is an analytic proof, and an elementay proof. Then I had heard that there is an landau's proof as well. That is why I think there are several proofs. I want to get an info about who has devised each of the proofs

Comment: It is the same proof presented differently and slightly improved. Also the PNT in Titchmarsh 1930 is proven in the "consequences of the RH" chapter (ie. a much stronger version of it but which can be easily adapted). It shows that many people worked on the topic, it doesn't come from a single person, except for Riemann who invented the field in his 1859 paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Riemann did *not* give a proof of the Prime Number Theorem.  He gave a sketch of an approach to proving it, and eventually his ideas did work out, but the necessary ingredients from the zeta-function turned out to be much less than was at first believed.  Ultimately all you need to know about the zeta-function outside its initial half-plane of convergence ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ is that it extends analytically to the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ except for a simple pole at $s = 1$.  No growth conditions for the zeta-function that line are needed; earlier proofs required such information (and a whole lot more, but as I already wrote, over time the proof was greatly simplified).

To address your questions:

1. Apostol's proof is similar to the proof in Ingham's book on the distribution of prime numbers (from the 1930s).  Both proofs involve working with $\psi_1(x) = \int_0^x \psi(y)\,dy$ instead of $\psi(x)$ directly. (Davenport writes in his book "Multiplicative Number Theory" that the idea of working with $\psi_1(x)$ instead of $\psi(x)$ goes back to de la Vallée Poussin's proof of PNT in 1896.)
2. *All* other proofs?!? It's more realistic to ask for some other proofs. Please clarify what it is you really want to know. Maybe you might like to read Narkiewicz's book "The Development of Prime Number Theory from Euclid to Hardy and Littlewood". He discusses what went into the first proofs of PNT by Hadamard and de la Vallée Poussin as well as Landau and the Tauberian approach, which is how the asymptotic relation in PNT is often proved today, especially if you are not interested in error terms but just a plain asymptotic relation.
3. If you just care about PNT as a pure asymptotic statement, then read D. J. Newman's proof.  It's from 1980 and is probably the simplest proof currently available.  You can find it in Jameson's book "The Prime Number Theorem" and many recently published analytic number theory books.

Comment: I am sure about what I have asked. For now I would like to see the list of all the proofs,

Comment: @SunShine I doubt anyone is going to give you a list of **all** the proofs, but you can check the Wikipedia article on the PNT for references on the three most well known proofs: the original, similar to the one in Apostol, the "elementary" proof by Selberg and Erdos and the "short" proof by D.J. Newman.

Comment: I don't think anyone has collected in one place all other proofs of PNT.  See Korevaar's book on Tauberian theorems and Ayoub's book "An Introduction to the Analytic Theory of Numbers" for examples of proofs that may not be easily found in other places (e.g., the proof by Hardy and Littlewood based on a Tauberian theorem for *power series* instead of Dirichlet series).

Comment: A proof was presented in Amer. Math. Monthly (which is not a journal of original research), circa 1968. It might be of interest, or it might have some useful references.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the proof of PNT by Newman appeared in the Amer. Math. Monthly: vol. 93, pp. 693--696.

Comment: Thanks @KCd. It helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just as a supplement to 3. There is a famous article by Don Zagier about [Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf-4iAkbPpAhXK2KQKHcCSD6YQFjACegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.gatech.edu%2F~mbaker%2Fpdf%2Fpnt2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1oyauvkEaN9WjIN3doIXf4), which certainly is worth studying. It has $4$ pages.